# Regular Expression (java) after word only whitespace or end of line

Tags: java, regex

how can I determine if this matches:

```
(WORD|DIGIT)(\\s*|$)
```

if word or digit is found - after that, a whitespace must follow - until it is not the end of line.. is this right?

Comment: Matches, matches what?

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\s+|$)
```

Try this.This should work for your case.

Comment: what does (?=\s+|$) do?

Comment: @user3630023 it will make sure you match only a word and not the space after.`?=` is a positive lookahaead which does not capture.It just checks.

Comment: hmmm i don't understand... 

?= means what ? the questionmark indicate only a lookahead - is that right? and what is the equals sign?

Comment: @user3630023 `?=` indicated lookahead